# How do i record the last 30 seconds in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, record, pyautogui

I have this code which records your screen. But I want to record what happened a few seconds ago. for example, 30 seconds ago. How do I do that?
I want it to be like the function which happens when you press `win key + alt + g`

```py
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np

resolution = (1920, 1080)
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")

filename = "Recording.mp4"

fps = 60.0
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, resolution)
cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270)

while True:
    img = pyautogui.screenshot()

    frame = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    out.write(frame)
    
    cv2.imshow('Live', frame)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Well, it can't magically go back in time and record something it wasn't recording before. Software that does this accomplishes so by *always* recording, and saving said recording whenever it is instructed to produce a clip

Comment: yea i thought so, but doesnt doing this reduce frame rate? and if i want to record it always. how do i do it?

Comment: that's just false. python isn't to blame. the APIs that accomplish this can be called from almost any programming language, and the code that does the heavy lifting is the same, regardless of what language it's called from. -- you need a method to capture the screen, and a method to funnel the data into the **hardware video codec** that's available on most modern computers. every desktop CPU and every GPU now comes with a hardware codec for H.264 and H.265. python would only call APIs.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I interpreted the question and the way OP was writing it as taking a more hands on approach to performing this task. In context of what they are doing, the behavior they described would occur, that being said, you raise a good point, I'll delete my comment

Comment: as for the time shift... different options. (1) buffer those frames in RAM, discard old ones, only write when told to record (2) always write to file, but write video segments, and delete files that aren't desired.

Comment: if you have enough RAM: Create a circular buffer that can hold 30 seconds of frames and which is filled all the time. Once your want to save the last 30 seconds, take that whole buffer and create a video file from it.

Comment: alright. thank you. Ill definitely try this.